Can it be proven that a number of this form can never be prime $f(n) = 1 + \sum_{x=1}^{n} 1234567890 \cdot 10^{10(x-1)+1}$
Can it be proven that a number of this form can never be prime
$$f(n) = 1 + \sum_{x=1}^{n} 1234567890 \cdot 10^{10(x-1)+1}$$
so far, I have checked for numbers up to n=10 and found no prime numbers but there doesn't seem to be any consistency/pattern in the factors either, also they all seem to be co-prime to one another
$f(1) = 857×14405693$
$f(2) = 11×5471×10000799×205126079$
$f(3) = 7742394596501×159455563099482401$
$f(4) = 29×43^2×55202177×2928109491677×1424415039563189$
$f(5) = 67×35671×2514203×20545870655930819766546995617806986531$
$f(6) = 33199×229722206431250878451×161877689092592502150094175437913849$
$f(7) = 36061×696107×9699829722837412321×50703402011560330613590446650721092952203$
$f(8) = 47×6421373951×1280828108120339×14720352532797110442529337×21696021207601055344738310431$
$f(9) = 97×4818423345047029411×2641425028577907664094089968410366264007585745358801565258650645620903$
$f(10) = 127×39655423×12058334129×203292499560829780372557442757089610398145711149105724532642336473476272361041989$

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

That's not a very deep search but, that said, unless you can produce an algebraic factoring the numbers grow so quickly that it will be hard to say much. Is there any context behind the expression that might clarify matters?

Isn't the factorization of $f(1)$ wrong? I get the number $1234567890\cdot 10^{11}+1$ which has factors $37\cdot 179\cdot 9881713\cdot 1886374799$.

The problem statement came up as a curiosity since I was trying to an algorithm which can produce large prime numbers quickly and this was one of the seed algorithms that we tried as you can see f(10) already produced a number with a prime  factor of the tune 10^80

@schiepy adjusting the expression

For what it is worth, if you replace 10 by 2, so that the function becomes $$f_2(n) = \sum_{x = 1}^{n} 12 \times 2^{2(x - 1) + 1}$$ then they are all composite numbers, until $f_2(18) = 549755813881$. So there might be counterexamples for large values of $n$.

Here is the first counter example : $f(17)$ is prime. The next one is $f(56)$.

Thanks your counter example helps, now I can fine tune my algorithm to find arbitrarily large prime numbers relatively fast
